# how to display image when "Permission is denied"

Tags: linux, error-handling

Out of curiosity, im looking for way of displaying an image when an error like "Permission is denied" appears on terminal

is there like a function or package that can replace this:

[image]

for this :

[image]

Comment: will you please share some code base ? and clarify what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I think what you're asking is that you want to change the `groupadd` function to display an image rather than an error. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I want to display this image when an error occurs with the terminal, like permission denied

Comment: == Super User and Apple Stack Exchange ==
Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww this question is a programming question, why would I go to Super User???

Comment: @PostMaloneM3m3r - Please show your code and I will retract the down vote and close vote.

Answer (score 0):

The "Permission denied" error comes from commands that you run and are not able to do their purpose because of lack of permissions.

You call these command from your shell (probably bash) and normally these commands sends their errors to stderr special file handle in Linux.

You could write your own shell (bash is open source), catch these errors and call a command like :

```
eog error.png
```

This kind of command will work only if and when you are in the graphic environment.

If you write a shell (let's say you call it myshell and place it in /usr/local/bin) - you could set yourself this shell as default shell by using chsh command (or editing /etc/passwd file as root).

Comment: ok but I don't have time to create a shell for this, Im just looking for something quick like a package or a function... thanks btw